# SystemVerilog ignore unused ports

Tags: system-verilog

I have a module that is instantiated many times in other modules. Two of the inputs to this module are used very rarely, and to avoid code bloat I don't want to have to connect them in every instantiation. Is there a way to mark these two ports to the compiler to indicate they can be left unconnected?

eg.

```
module mymod(input logic foo, unused1, unused2, output logic out);
//...
endmodule


module top(...);
//...
mymod(.foo(1'b0));
endmodule
```

will not compile due to port mismatch errors. How can I change the code so `unused1` and `unused2` don't need to be connected?

Comment: Ignoring the syntax error in the above code where you forgot a name for the module instance, that code compiles just fine for me for multiple tools (though they do throw warnings).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can specify a default value for a unconnected port (See 23.2.2.4 Default port values in the 1800-2017 LRM)

```
module mymod(input logic foo, unused1='0, unused2='0, output logic out);
//...
endmodule
```

Another option is to explicitly leave these ports unconnected when instantiating.

```
mymod(.foo(1'b0), .unused1(), .unused2() );
```

But in either case, your tool may have specific requirements with unconnected ports that you will have to deal with as they ask you to do.